# Performing Bulk insert into a DB Table using Apache Cayenne

Tags: java, mysql, database, orm, apache-cayenne

Is there any way to perform bulk insert into a DB table using Apache Cayenne. There are some scenarios for me where I need to perform bulk insert. I am not sure how can we do this in Cayenne.

Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways - [EJBQLQuery](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/ejbqlquery.html) and [SQLTemplate](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/sqltemplate-basics.html). EJBQLQuery can be used if you can express your query in therms of the object model. E.g.:

```
UPDATE Publisher pub SET pub.status = 'outstanding' WHERE pub.revenue < 1000000
```

Otherwise use SQLTemplate. It even allows batching of multiple parameter sets (see 'setParameters').